# Need to print all the records from the text files including the ones that are affected in AWK

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
awk '{printf "%-80s %-5s %-50s %-10s %-2s %-10s %-10s %-30s %-9s %-40s %-22s %-12s %-18s", $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $24, $25, $26}1' FS='|' OFS="\t" $path/datafile_1.txt > $path/datafile_2.txt
```

I have a pipe delimited text file as input which has certain columns which have to be specific in terms of the space allotted to each field. I want to print all the columns in the tab delimited format as seen from the above code. 
But when I run this code, it outputs all the columns from 13 only. And at the end of the 26th column it prints all the columns since I have given a 1 at the end. 
I thought the 1 would be useful to print all columns in tab limited format but it isn't helping me.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. And we do **not** need to see or hear about anything with 26 columns for you to explain and demonstrate your problem - reduce it to half a dozen or so columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
awk -F\| '{for(i=1;i<=12;i++) printf "%s\t", $i; 
           printf "%-80s\t%-5s\t...%-18s\n", $13, $14, ..., $26 }' file > output
```

fill in the `...` note the `\t` and `\n` in format string.